# Изменить код под статичный массив (c++)

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток. Есть код, который нужно изменить под статичный массив. Как из статичного в динамический переделать - я знаю. А как сделать код который заранее построен на динамическом - не могу понять. Ниже будет представлен код программы. Надеюсь на вашу помощь!)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
int N, a, b;
cout << "Enter a matrix size:" << "\n";
cout << "N = ";
cin >> N;
cout << "Enter a left boundary:" << "\n";
cout << "a = ";
cin >> a;
cout << "Enter a right boundary:" << "\n";
cout << "b = ";
cin >> b;
int** arr = new int*[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    arr[i] = new int[N];
}
cout << "A random matrix:" << "\n";
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        arr[i][j] = a + rand() % (b - a);
        cout.width(3);
        cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
{
    swap(arr[0][i], arr[N-i-1][N-1]);
}
cout << "Target matrix:" << "\n";
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {

        cout.width(3);
        cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    delete [] arr[i];
}
delete [] arr;
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если динамические массивы использовать нельзя (и видимо stl/vector также), то нужно так

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
const int MAXN = 100; // подбирается экспериментально
int N, a, b;
cout << "Enter a matrix size:" << "\n";
cout << "N = ";
cin >> N;
if (N > MAXN) { // перестрахуемся.
    cout << "Ups!";
    return 1;
}
cout << "Enter a left boundary:" << "\n";
cout << "a = ";
cin >> a;
cout << "Enter a right boundary:" << "\n";
cout << "b = ";
cin >> b;
int arr[MAXN][MAXN];

cout << "A random matrix:" << "\n";
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        arr[i][j] = a + rand() % (b - a);
        cout.width(3);
        cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
{
    swap(arr[0][i], arr[N-i-1][N-1]);
}
cout << "Target matrix:" << "\n";
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {

        cout.width(3);
        cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, как раз то что нужно!)